Google Drive API saying insufficient scopes to fetch drive info API
So I have an app which authenticates with Google Drive and allows you to query files in Drive for information like file name, size and type. For the vast majority of users the scopes I've seem to work without an issue. But a few of them are seeing this issue.

The scopes I'm using are : [ "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" ]
The API where it fails is: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/about/get
I also did find this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en#:~:text=Restrict%20or%20unrestrict%20Google%20services,restricted%20or%20unrestricted%20data%20access which says that a Google Workspace Admin will have to allow these scopes. I do not have any context on Google Workspace, looking for someone to confirm!

Can you add on your post more information about how you implemented authentication workflows, what type of credentials did you use? You said that some people were able to do it and only a few are experiencing an issue did you see any pattern with them? Please add this information on the post just to give the community a better oversight on what is going on your project.

Because you added the scope after you already authorized the user and your running off an old refresh token or access token.  you need to authorize the user again after you change scopes   please edit your question and include [example]
